How to smooth cylinder with triangles
I have a 3d model imported from another software that I am trying to smooth. I only want to smooth the cylindrical part so that it does not cast a polygonal shadow as shown in the second image. The challenge is all the tutorials show how to do this with cylinders composed of quads (i.e. they subdivide it) but this model is made of tris. So any idea how I can get rid of the polygonal shadow in the render?



for a shape that simple redoing it is probably the fastest way.

Is this Cycles, or EEVEE? Those shadows don’t look like they match the geometry.

@TheLabCat This is cycles

@MarkusvonBroady I can't redo it since it's imported from another software and the rest of the geometry (not shown in image) is not simple.

Is the part shown that is not in edit mode actually cylindrical as it appears? Is there anything else affecting the lighting, like it being an array of point lights or something else being closer to it that could be casting this shadow?

could be also wrong normals
